# Class interaction tips

Tags: c++, oop, class, class-design

I am puzzled by some issues when trying to design interacting classes.

If a class A needs some data from class B, either in the form of a pointer or standard container format, (or even lets become more ambitious and say in the form of some shared_ptr members to stl containers.), my way is to use a function that returns the same kind of arguments and design class B methods with conforming arguments? Are there a general rules of thumb for designing interacting classes and share data between these classes? 
Could you please draw a general scheme for some common situations that are generally encountered in practice(and along some examples are appreciated)? I guess I should read some examples on class interaction in C++, any pointers on this are also appreciated?

A small sample could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        A(int s, int val):sz(s), val(val), v(new vector<int>){}
        int fill_vector(){ 
          for(int k=0;k!=sz;++k)
            v->push_back(val);
          return 0;
        }      
        ~A(){  
          cout << "Dtor is deleting the pointer to vector\n"; 
          delete v;
        }      
        vector<int>* get_pointer_to_vector_in_A(){ return v; }
    private:
        int sz, val;
        vector<int> *v;
};

class B{
    public:
        B(){} // does nothing basically
        int print_vector_contents_from_A( vector<int> *v_from_A ) const
        {      
          assert(!v_from_A->empty());
          copy(v_from_A->begin(), v_from_A->end(),
               ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n") );
        }
};

int main()
{
  A a(10, 4);
  a.fill_vector();
  B b;
  b.print_vector_contents_from_A( a.get_pointer_to_vector_in_A() );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It rather depends on what `A` is, conceptually. If `A` can be validly viewed as a sequence of `int`, then I'd implement `size_t size() const` and `int &operator[](size_t)` (+ its `const` counterpart) on it. These can just delegate their activities to `v.size` and `v[]` or `v.at`.

In `B`, you can then define

```
static void B::print_contents(A const &a)
{
    for (size_t i=0; i < a.size(); i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
}
```

A member that returns an `std::vector<int>*` breaks encapsulation: you can never change the implementation of `A` away from `std::vector<int>` except with very ugly hacks to ensure `get_pointer_to_vector_in_A` still works with the same semantics.

Comment: Thanks, actually the source of the question comes from the fact that I should somehow share some data which is in the form of a vector. I guess I understand your point, for encapsulation, however for this implementation, this is not a template class so even in that case is that right that encapsulation is broken if I use a vector? I mean I do reach that through functions of A...

Comment: Encapsulation is broken because you expose implementation details through the interface. `A` cannot be efficiently implemented with anything other than `std::vector`, because that is what it exports.

Comment: "Encapsulation is broken because you expose implementation details through the interface" is not clear to me what I reveal is that I use a std::vector, is this encapsulation breaking?. And you mean I should use a typedef or so, Or as you did in your code, put extra overloaded operator to hide the implementation details? I guess I had a conceptual misunderstanding on encapsulation which is clear I guess now.

Comment: `A`'s client knows that there's an `std::vector`, or something emulating it through crude hacks, in `A`. If `A`'s purpose is to store `int`s, then how it stores them (`vector`, array, `std::list`) is an implementation detail that should not be known to the client.

Comment: But if class B is using that with a utility function, then there is no problem, since that is internal and not usable by the clients, right?

Comment: @Umut: what do you mean by a utility function?

Comment: A private function in class B that is used by a function in the public interface of B, just a workaround, I sometimes do this but want to know good practices.

Comment: The problem is not `B` exposing its innards, but `A`. Everyone can see `A`'s implementation.

Comment: Still not clear, although not important but I do not want to miss some points, say I have print(vector<int>* a) as a private function in B and I call this from within a function print() that is on the public interface of B, in this case how can you expose the details of A to B, am I still wrong at some point?

Comment: You need a way to get the `vector<int>*` out of `A`. Whether `B` uses it in a `public`, `private` or `protected` member doesn't matter: it has knowledge of `A` that it shouldn't have. The classes are too tightly coupled and `A` is exposing itself. (You could make `B` a `friend` of `A`, but that's still too tight a coupling.)

Comment: Ok, I guess I got the point so what I should do then as you did in your example just take the other object as an argument and do what I would like to do inside the function using the methods from A, is this the way that should be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One great one-directional way to do this is:

```
class A {
public:
  void fill_vector();
  int vec_size() const { return vec.size(); }
  int get_data(int i) const { return vec[i]; }
};
class B {
public:
  B(A &a) : a(a) { }
  void init() { a.fill_vector(); }
  void fetch_and_print() 
    { for(int i=0;i<a.vec_size();i++) std::cout << a.get_data(i); }
private:
  A &a;
};
int main() {
  A a;
  B b(a);
  b.init();
  b.fetch_and_print();
}
```

The constructor parameter for class B is the important bit.